# Problem running web server through perl script

Tags: .net, system.net.webexception

I am starting a web server(Cassini) on a remote machine through a perl script from my local machine. I am also specifying the virtual path, root directory settings, etc.

However, I am not able to request files from the server as its giving me

```
System.Net.WebException : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

However, when I do request files by starting the server directly from the remote machine itself, it works fine.

Any reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that the web server is not being started from your script.

**Edit**

Have you doubled checked all the settings to make sure you didn't miss one?

Comment: It was a problem with the web server write-access settings on some folders. I was able to fix it myself.